# Recurrent local push notifications for react-native

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native, push-notification

I'm making a mobile app which needs heavy use of recurring notification settings (repeat daily, monthly, hourly, every weekdays, every weekends, every 2 hours, etc ...).

I've tried [`react-native-push-notification`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) (only supports `repeatType`: `week`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `time`), and also checked [`react-native-notifications`](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications). But none of them allows me to make highly customized recurring notifications like that.

Have anyone done this using `react-native` without writing native code?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule did u try this?

Comment: @DroiDev I doubt it will work for react-native environment. It may work when the app is active, but probably wouldn't if it's inactive or closed.

Comment: @haotang I've done push notifications including scheduled push notifications without writing native code. I've done both local and remote notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background job to run your notification logic and send/schedule local push notifications. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-job. Sadly it works for Android only.

Though I find [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library works pretty good, especially for scheduling local push notifications:

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule(details: Object)
```

If you need remote push notifications, your notification server should be responsible for sending notifications in the scheduled time. I needed scheduled push notifications for both Android and iOS and I tried both local and remote and I ended up using remote notifications. My server is responsible for sending them in the specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating notifications are supported by [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

See the part in the [documentation](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#repeating-notifications).

Basically you need to add `repeatType:'day'` (or else such configuration) prop to your `scheduleNotif` object.